# Angular-google-chart - building and sorting the data-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I'm using the [Google Chart Tools Directive Module](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart) to draw a line/area chart in my Angularjs application, from rdf data retrieved via sparql queries and available, within the app, in json-like format.

In the main controller I declared my drawing function like this:

```
$scope.createChart = function () {           

        var json1 = $scope.entities     // here I have my data                   
        var rows = []

        // populate rows with data:
        for (var key in json1) {
            // json1 has extra data I don't need 
            if (json1[key]['sdmx-dimension:refTime'] && json1[key]['dpc:deads']) {
                var date = new Date(json1[key]['sdmx-dimension:refTime']);                           
                var deads = json1[key]['dpc:deads']
                rows.push({ c: [ { v:date }, { v:deads } ] })
            }
        }  

        $scope.myChartObject = {
          "type": "AreaChart",
          "data": {
            "cols": [
              {
                "id": "date",
                "label": "Date",
                "type": "date"
              },
              {
                "id": "deaths",
                "label": "Deaths",
                "type": "number"
              }                     
            ]
          },
          "options": {
            "title": "Deaths trend",                
            "height": 400,
            "width": 600,
            "vAxis": {
              "title": "Deaths",
            },
            "hAxis": {
              "title": "Date"
            }
          }
        }

        // attach the rows to the chart object
        $scope.myChartObject.data.rows = rows

        // template containing the chart
        $scope.callTemplate('drawChart', '#right', true)
}

// wait for sparql query to retrieve data before create chart
// otherwise an empty chart will be drawn!
window.setTimeout( function(){ $scope.createChart() }, 3000);
```

With this solution I'm able to draw the chart with data but the problem is: **dates are not sorted** correctly so the trend line is zigzagging over the chart:

[image: area chart]

I've tried to use a sort function on rows array:

```
rows.sort([{column:0}])
```

but the final order is even worse than initial one.

And I can't use sort on the chart object like this:

```
$scope.myChartObject.data.sort([{column:0}])
```

because this is not an array.

Dates come in this format: `'yyyy-mm-dd'` (e.g. `'2020-02-24'`) 
and nothing seems to improve even if I modify it to `'yyyy, mm, dd'` before the *new Date* assignment.

Here `console.log(myCharObject)`:

[image]

and here if I print `{{myCharObject}}` variable in html template:

[image]

How to sort this dates? 
Should I use some other way to define my chart as described [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#creating-and-populating-a-datatable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to sort an array of objects, you will need to provide a custom sort function.

try using the following to sort `rows`, before adding to the chart data...

```
// sort
rows.sort(function (rowA, rowB) {
  return rowA.c[0].v.getTime() - rowB.c[0].v.getTime();
});
```

e.g.

```
    // populate rows with data:
    for (var key in json1) {
        // json1 has extra data I don't need 
        if (json1[key]['sdmx-dimension:refTime'] && json1[key]['dpc:deads']) {
            var date = new Date(json1[key]['sdmx-dimension:refTime']);                           
            var deads = json1[key]['dpc:deads']
            rows.push({ c: [ { v:date }, { v:deads } ] })
        }
    }  

    // sort
    rows.sort(function (rowA, rowB) {
      return rowA.c[0].v.getTime() - rowB.c[0].v.getTime();
    });
```

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
// test data
var rows = [];
rows.push({c: [{v: new Date(2020, 2, 1)}, {v: 7}]});
rows.push({c: [{v: new Date(2020, 1, 1)}, {v: 7}]});
rows.push({c: [{v: new Date(2020, 0, 1)}, {v: 7}]});

// before sort
console.log("row 1 before", rows[0].c[0].v);

// sort
rows.sort(function (rowA, rowB) {
  return rowA.c[0].v.getTime() - rowB.c[0].v.getTime();
});

// after sort
console.log("row 1 after", rows[0].c[0].v);
```

Comment: Bravo! I was trying with a custom sort function but I was making the comparison without the last  ```.v.getTime()``` part